# Using split to populate a column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with text data and I would simply like to populate a new column based on an existing column.

Example: the column `sourceEncodedID` may have values like `a.b.c` and I'd like to extract only the second part of the string, `b`, if there's a second part available. Here are some example values:

```
sourceEncodedID    Branch    
a.b.c               b    
c.r.d               r    
a                   a    
p                   p
```

To achieve this, I have come up with the following code:

```
for i in range(0,20350):
    if len(str(artifacts.sourceEncodedID[i]).split('.')) > 1:
        artifacts['branch'][i] = str(artifacts.sourceEncodedID[i]).split('.')[1]
    else:
        artifacts['branch'][i] = str(artifacts.sourceEncodedID[i])
```

There are only 20k rows in the dataframe and yet this piece of code take minutes to execute, before never finishing and rendering my browser unreponsive (I'm using `ipython notebook`). I would have thought this would run in a couple of seconds.

Is there something obviously silly in this code that I'm unable to catch? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** - i believe this will be bit faster:

```
x['new'] = x.sourceEncodedID.str.replace(r'[^\.]*\.([^\.]*).*', r'\1')
```

Timing on 20K DF:

```
In [155]: x.shape
Out[155]: (20000, 2)

In [156]: %timeit x['new'] = x.sourceEncodedID.str.replace(r'[^\.]*\.([^\.]*).*', r'\1')
10 loops, best of 3: 127 ms per loop
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [68]: x['new'] = x.sourceEncodedID

In [69]: x
Out[69]:
  sourceEncodedID Branch    new
0           a.b.c      b  a.b.c
1           c.r.d      r  c.r.d
2               a      a      a
3               p      p      p

In [70]: x.ix[x.sourceEncodedID.str.contains('\.'), 'new'] = x.sourceEncodedID.str.split('\.', expand=True)[1]

In [71]: x
Out[71]:
  sourceEncodedID Branch new
0           a.b.c      b   b
1           c.r.d      r   r
2               a      a   a
3               p      p   p
```

when working with pandas data frames first always try to find vectorized solution. And only if it's absolutely not possible then double-check it and only after that try loop through approach, as it will be orders of magnitude slower.

**OLD answer:**

try this:

```
In [61]: x.sourceEncodedID.str.split('\.', expand=True)[1]
Out[61]:
0       b
1       r
2    None
3    None
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it did the job. Would you please be able to point out the silliness which isn't obvious to me, in my code?

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation, I appreciate it !
I guess it's just a little frustrating coz one HAS to know the vectorized functions of pandas and going back to basics costs you in terms of time. I agree vectorized solutions are more neat but you have to know them. One function at a time !!